# JupyterHub with C# kernels under the docker container

Tags: c#, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am trying to create docker container to run C# jupyter kernels for different user under jupyterhub. I do it as follow: I put *Dockerfile*, *config.py*, *jupyterhub_users.py* into folder then build and run it.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOME /root

RUN apt-get update  && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https -y && \
    apt-get install wget -y

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -O Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -q
RUN bash Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/anaconda3
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
RUN conda init bash && \
    conda update -n base -c defaults conda

RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb -q
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt-get update  && \
    apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.0 -y && \
    apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1 -y
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-try
ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools
RUN dotnet try jupyter install

RUN conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub && \
    conda install notebook

RUN jupyter-kernelspec install /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/.net-csharp

COPY config.py config.py
COPY jupyterhub_users.py jupyterhub_users.py
RUN python config.py
```

*config.py*:

```
import os
import jupyterhub_users

for user_group in [jupyterhub_users.admins, jupyterhub_users.users]:
    for user_name, user_password in user_group.items():
        bash_command = f'adduser {user_name} --disabled-password --force-badname --gecos "User" --home /home/{user_name} --shell /bin/bash --quiet'
        print(bash_command)
        os.system(bash_command)
        bash_command = f'echo "{user_name}:{user_password}" | chpasswd'
        os.system(bash_command)
        print(bash_command)
jupyterhub_configs = [
    'c.Spawner.args = [\'--allow-root\']\n',
    'c.Spawner.cmd = [\'jupyterhub-singleuser\']\n',
    'c.Spawner.default_url = \'/lab\'\n',
    'c.Authenticator.admin_users = {%s}\n' % ', '.join([f'\'{u}\'' for u in jupyterhub_users.admins.keys()]),
    'c.Authenticator.whitelist = {%s}\n' % ', '.join([f'\'{u}\'' for u in jupyterhub_users.users.keys()])
]
os.system('mkdir /etc/jupyterhub/')
with open('/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(''.join(jupyterhub_configs))
```

*jupyterhub_users.py* - contains two dictionaries: admins, users.

and then all I need is to execute **jupyterhub -f /etc/juptyerhub/jupyterhub_config.py**. But there is a some tricky thing: I can login as any of created user, but I can't run C# cells, but if I interrupt jupyterhub and change appropriate line in /etc/passwd (user:x:0:0:User,,,:/home/user:/bin/bash - I suppose that I have change user and group id for user) then I am able to run C# kernel, but if I log out I can't login back.

So I can login and can't run C# kernel or I can't login and can run C# kernel.

So how to set permissions for created users properly?

Comment: RUNing `chmod -R a+rwX /root` and RUNing `chown -R :{user_name} /root` for each user allows to any user be able to run dotnet try and run c# kernel.

Comment: but how safe is it ?